# Copy only specific rows from one table to another and create a new row for each row information

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy only specific rows from one table to another. So far so good:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM HDG.HDG_FINAL_TABLE WHERE HDG.HDG_FINAL_TABLE.FARBFAMILIE LIKE "%,%";
UPDATE tmptable_1 SET primarykey = NULL;
INSERT INTO HDG.HDG_FINAL_TABLE_2 SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;
```

My problem is that the column "FARBFAMILIE" got three different values like "black, blue, yellow". I want to copy each row where the column "FARBFAMILIE" contains a "," and duplicate this row as often as the column contains different informations split by ",".

**Original row:**

*column 0 - column1 - column2*

Group - SKU - Color

1 - 001 - black, blue, yellow

**Aim:**

*column 0 - column1 - column2*

Group - SKU -Color

1 - 001 - black

1 - 001 - blue

1 - 001 - yellow

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try googling "MySQL Split Function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do a noble thing, by getting rid of comma delimited columns.  It is not that easy, but you can do it.  First, you need to know the maximum number of values in the column:

```
select 1 + max(length(FARBFAMILIE) - length(replace(FARBFAMILIE), ',', ''))
from HDG.HDG_FINAL_TABLE;
```

Notice the trick here for counting the elements.  Take the length of the value and subtract the length without commas.

Then, you can get the rows you want as:

```
select `group`, sku,
       substring_index(substring_index(color, ',', n.n), ',', -1) as color
from HDG.HDG_FINAL_TABLE join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 . . .
     ) n
     on length(FARBFAMILIE) - length(replace(FARBFAMILIE), ',', '') <= n.n;
```

This will produce the output rows with a separate color on each row.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! Worked well

Comment: Gordon one last question:
(a) the first value before the "," is always missing (e.g. "black"), don`t know why and (b) I want to apply the code to several columns step by step (15 columns) so it is the case that the column "FARBFAMILIE" contains 3 colors or less/more. How can I keep the "(select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3)" dynamic?

Comment: (a) Try using `', '` instead of `','` for the substring indexes.  Maybe that is throwing things off.  (b) It helps if you have a table of numbers, but there are some tricks that are too long for a comment.

Comment: thanks for your help.

(a) I added 3 spaces, 1 in the substring, 2 in the length statement. (b) I just added 12 selects (the max info in one column is 12) so I have a lot of duplicates but get rid of them afterwards.

Nevertheless I have a final question... :) the whole query opens 2 windows, one with the number of attributes and the second one shows the data. How I can save the data in another table? I know how to save it but mysql says "number of columns doesnt match" and I think thats because of the 1 window (number of attributes). I just want to save the second window

Comment: @user3802349 . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.